# Can't "continue" if I pipe output to tee

Tags: bash, io-redirection, continue, curly-braces

I have a bash script that does pretty-much what I want using the following structure:

```sh
for x in 1 2 3
do
  {
  [[ $x -ne 2 ]] || continue
  echo $x
  } &>> foo.log
done
```

I need to change it so the output goes both to the terminal and the log file.  This, however, doesn't work:

```sh
for x in 1 2 3
do
  {
  [[ $x -ne 2 ]] || continue
  echo $x
  } 2>&1 | tee -a foo.log
done
```

It looks like, by creating a process, the pipe prevents me from using `continue`.

Of course, I could rewrite the logic of my script without `continue`, but before I jump into that, I'm wondering if I'm missing a more straightforward way to achieve what I want.

Comment: The commands in a pipeline run in subprocesses; a subprocess cannot change control flow (or change variables, or...) in the parent shell process. Therefore, `continue`, `break`, `exit`, etc can't have full effect when in a pipeline.

Comment: That's why I said: "by creating a process".  My question is not "why is continue rejected here".

Answer (score 4):

You could redirect the output to a process substitution.

```
for x in 1 2 3
do
  {
  [[ $x -ne 2 ]] || continue
  echo $x
  } 2>&1 > >(tee -a foo.log)
done |
# I suggest to do pipe the output to ex. `cat`, so that the output 
# of process substitution will be synchronized with rest of the script
cat
```

But why not just redirect the output of the whole loop?

```
for x in 1 2 3; do
  [[ $x -ne 2 ]] || continue
  echo $x
done 2>&1 | tee -a foo.log
```

You could exit from the subprocess. If you would do that, I would suggest replacing `{` `}` with `(` `)` just to be safe if you one day decide to remove the `tee`.

```
for x in 1 2 3
do
  {
  [[ $x -ne 2 ]] || exit
  echo $x
  } 2>&1 | tee -a foo.log
done
```

Comment: I can't redirect the whole loop (there's a cd in it, so the output is actually sent to separate log files).  I like the "process substitution" idea.  It's a syntax I'm not familiar with.  However, I don't understand the comment "to do pipe the output to...".  The "exit" approach is a bit scarier, but might be the easiest (with a big fat comment to remember not to remove the pipe).  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Compare the output of  `echo 1 > >(sleep 1; tee something)` with `echo 1 > >(sleep 1; tee something) | cat`. The problem is is the `>(part)` is run in the background, so if it is slower then the rest of the script, it's output will be run asynchronously with other commands. So `echo 1 > >(tee something); echo 2` may result in printing first `2` then `1`. To synchronize it, pipe it. Pipe makes sure that process substitution ends before running next command.

Comment: But then the "| cat" reintroduces the "continue" problem I'm trying to solve! ;-)  I might go the "exit" route...

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you I was looking for this process substitution trick!